External SSD refuses to connect with a USB-C cable
TL;DR
Having trouble connecting an external SSD to my 2021 MacBook Pro with Apple M1 Pro via a specific Satechi USB-C cable.
That specific cable does not work on my M1 MacBook Pro but works if I go through a USB-C hub and also works fine on a M3.



Device
Connection type
Connected to
Result




SanDisk SSD
Satechi USB-C to USB-C First cable bought
2021 MacBook Pro M1
Fail


SanDisk SSD
Satechi USB-C to USB-C Replacement cable
2021 MacBook Pro M1
Fail


SanDisk SSD
Satechi USB-C to USB-C via i-tec USB-C Hub
2021 MacBook Pro M1
Success


SanDisk SSD
Sandisk original USB-C to USB-A cable via i-tec USB-C Hub
2021 MacBook Pro M1
Success


SanDisk SSD
BenQ OEM USB-C to USB-C cable
2021 MacBook Pro M1
Success


SanDisk SSD
Satechi USB-C to USB-C
2023 MacBook Pro M3
Success


SanDisk SSD
Satechi USB-C to USB-C
2023 MacBook Pro M3
Success


BenQ PD2706U
Satechi USB-C to USB-C
2021 MacBook Pro M1
Fail


BenQ PD2706U
Satechi USB-C to USB-C via i-tec USB-C Hub
2021 MacBook Pro M1
Fail


BenQ PD2706U
BenQ OEM USB-C to USB-C cable
2021 MacBook Pro M1
Success


BenQ PD2706U
BenQ OEM USB-C to USB-C cable via i-tec USB-C Hub
2021 MacBook Pro M1
Success



Long story
I had the SSD connected to a USB hub (USB-C on the SSD and USB-A in the hub) and never had any issues.
I decided to drop the hub and connect the SSD straight to the Mac and therefore purchased a 10 inch Satechi USB-C to USB-C cable.
When I plugged the SSD using the new cable, nothing happened. I tried all ports on the mac and none worked.
I don't see the SSD in the Finder and in Disk Utility. I went back to the shop and had the cable replaced as I thought it was defective.
I tried with the replacement cable and the same happened. So I tried with a 3rd cable that I had at home and it worked straight away.
So I went back to the shop a 3rd time, with their cable, my SSD and my working cable. They connected my SSD to 4 different new MacBooks, with the cable I bought there and the one I had at home and it worked straight away on all 4 Macs with both cables.
I just tried connecting the SSD with the new cable to my USB hub and the hub to the Mac and it works too.
What on earth could be the issue??

If you do some light research you will see there’s many tools needed and good summaries of the need to select carefully which cable and setup you use. (Even legit vendors can ship bad cables, but lower price often are due to lack of consistency or shortcuts in safety and design and assembly and testing.) YOJOCK USB C Tester https://a.co/d/52bW5Cq and https://www.zdnet.com/home-and-office/smart-office/using-the-wrong-usb-c-cable-can-damage-your-tech-heres-how-to-avoid-that/

@bmike why would it work fine on a similar macbook then with the same cable and same SSD? Satechi cable and SSD drive.

Reading the tech specs of the cable, it sounds like the Satechi cable is more of a charge only cable rather than a charge & sync cable.  When you drill down into the specs, the max data x-fer rate is 480Mbs whereas a proper sync cable can handle 20Gbps.  This is likely the weak link in your chain.

@Allan thanks for the info. But even with a weak transfer rate, the disk should still be able to be mounted and accessed, isn't it? When I use that cable to my USB hub,  the disk is detected, I can read, write and transfer files with no issues.

I did a write up on charge only cables and how they eliminate conductors to save $$. The correct cable is essential for a good connection.

That cable obviously has all the connectors. It's not a charge-only cable. Proof is that it works on other Macs and via a USB hub. I did not know about the specs when I bought it and I am not saying it's the right cable. But I still believe it should work.

What version of macOS?  I ask because people have reported (elsewhere) mounting issues with Apple silicon and Sonoma which are fixed by 14.4.1.

I am on 14.4.1.

The cable you are referring to can only do power delivery to 100 W and USB 2.0 (480 Mb/s). The SSD has an USB 3.1 Gen 2 (10 Gb/s) interface. An Apple M1 Pro can handle that speed (and much faster speeds).
This cable is the wrong choice for Mac with USB C ports. If you wanted to stay with the same brand, you would want this cable (the 10 inch one), which is considerably higher in price.
Time could be spent trying to determine why the drive is not recognized by the Mac when directly plugged in using the cable you purchased. However, I would consider this as a waste of time, since the connection speed would be about 4.8% of the drive maximum transfer speed.
According to the link you gave, the drive was supposed to have both an "USB Type C cable and Type A cable included". You might try to determine what happened to the USB Type C cable.
Examples of possible replacement cables (from MyCableMart.com) are given below. (Note: USB 3.1 Gen 2 = USB 3.2 Gen 2 = USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 and all three are 10 Gb/s)
6 inch
1.5 foot

You might try to determine what happened to the USB Type C cable - good one! Yeah, it might be somewhere :)

That USB 2.0 info is well hidden and the cable box says Power delivery and Data transfer... That said, I would still expect the SSD to be detected by my Mac even with a USB 2 connection. And why would it work with the same cable when plugged to a USB hub? That's really weird.

When I purchased my Samsung T7 SSD, I only needed the Type A cable. Kept the Type C cable in the box. One day a mentioned the cable was still in the box. I suppose that was permission. I just looked in the box and the cable is gone. Zero chance anyone is going to admit (or remember) taking the cable. Then again, I borrowed a Thunderbolt 2 cable to connect my 2011 and 2013 iMacs together. One day the owner inquired about its whereabouts. I never said a word.

After turning the house upside down, I found this and I can confirm all works fine!
